# how to change the location of a text in a layout

Tags: android, textview

everyone i have this

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Tablet"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

i want that my TextView take the Center of of the layout that's all thank you

Comment: Is using a LinearLayout mandatory? Because using a RelativeLayout makes it easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just add the gravity  in this textview

```
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"//here you can set any thing....
```

if you used the relative layout means you can use this one for alignment ...

```
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:layout_gravity="center"` property of `TextView`

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Tablet"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not impossible with LinearLayout, you should use FrameLayout or RelativeLayout.
The Gravity attributes works for FrameLayout

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Tablet"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```